# Twitter streaming API not tracking URLs

Tags: twitter

Have gone through https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters

Per documentation it should be able to track URLs such as example.com/foobarbaz but I can't seem it to be tracking such URLs. It just doesn't return me any result when I tweet this URL and track it using Streaming API. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm also unable to get the streaming API to track URLs.  Did you have any luck with this in the end?  For example: `https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=cnn` works, but `https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=www.cnn.com` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late, but I found this by Google so this might help someone...

There are a few answers to this. The main answer being that Twitter treats URLs differently than anything else.

First, make sure you do NOT include the "www".

> Twitter currently canonicalizes the domain “www.example.com” to “example.com” before the match is performed, so omit the “www” from URL track terms.

For me, sending the track parameter as "example.com/foobarz" and then tweeting "a test, please ignore: http://example.com/foobarz" worked perfectly.

You can NOT, in general, ask for substrings of URLs:

> URLs are considered words for the purposes of matches which means that the entire domain and path must be included in the track query for a Tweet containing an URL to match.

But if you are willing to take every tweet from the whole domain (and a bit more edge cases), Twitter will accommodate:

> Finally, to address a common use case where you may want to track all mentions of a particular domain name (i.e., regardless of subdomain or path), you should use “example com” as the track parameter for “example.com” (notice the lack of period between “example” and “com” in the track parameter).

All quotes are from the Twitter docs: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track

They have more information, including examples.

Good luck!